# Is there something like bytes(byte...b):byte[]?

Tags: java, guava

i am looking for a simple method were i can pass in some bytes, as varargs, and get a byte[] returned, like:

```
static byte[] byteArray(byte ...bytes){ return bytes;}
```

What i found so far...

`java.lang.Byte` doesn't have it
`java.util.Arrays` doesn't have it
 
`com.google.common.primitives.Bytes.toArray(..)` want a Collection

sample use case: `assertThat(actualArray,is(byteArray(1,2,3,4,5)));`

Comment: And why is `byteArray(1,2,3,4,5)` better than `new byte[] {1,2,3,4,5}`?

Comment: You just wrote the method! You can use that!

Comment: Okay, my sample implementation is not the best because `byteArray(0xca,0xfe,0xba,0xbe)` won't compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're assigning the bytes to a variable or field of type `byte[]`, you can write this even more compactly than `new byte[]{1, 2, 3, 4}`:

```
byte[] bytes = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

Also, the problem with `0xca, 0xfe, 0xba, 0xbe` is that all of those values are actually outside the legal range for a Java `byte`, since `byte` in Java is *signed* by default.

Perhaps you want a method that takes an argument of type `long...` and returns a `byte[]`, using [UnsignedBytes.checkedCast](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/UnsignedBytes.html#checkedCast%28long%29) or [UnsignedBytes.saturatedCast](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/UnsignedBytes.html#saturatedCast%28long%29) to convert each value.

Comment: `UnsignedBytes.checkedCast(long value)` would do the trick ! Sadly Guava lacks such a feature...

Comment: @Chriss: Guava does have `UnsignedBytes.checkedCast(long value)`. Do you mean it doesn't have a version of that for converting an array? That's true, but it's easy enough to write one yourself. You could also make a feature request, though I'm not sure if it would be considered a common enough requirement to be added to the class.

Comment: Right, what i want to say was: Sadly is has no `UnsignedBytes.checkedCast(int...v):byte[]`. I'm not sure too if my request is common enough for Guava. I think i start implementing it in my personal _uncommon_-Lib. Thanks for help @ColinD

Comment: To write a byte like 0xca you just have to write "(byte) 0xca". Annoying, but simple.

Answer (score 6):

There is no function for that because

```
new byte[]{1,2,3,4,5}
```

is also quite short.

**Edit:**
Please note that any helper method like this

```
static byte[] toBytes(byte ... bytes)
{
   return bytes;
}
```

has the same problem as `new byte{...}`: All arguments must be *real* bytes and not propagated to `int`. So arguments like `0xca` must be casted to `byte`in both cases:

```
byte ba1[] = new byte[]{ (byte)0xca };
byte ba2[] = toBytes( (byte)0xca );
```

If you want easier input then you must write a custom method which allocates a byte array and do the coping and casting by hand.

Comment: What about `0xca,0xfe,0xba,0xbe` ? it would become far longer
`new byte[]{(byte)0xca,(byte)0xfe,(byte)0xba,(byte)0xbe}`

Comment: Updated answer for your comment.